# Посчитать разницу во времени относительно старого времени к более новому для каждой строки

Tags: sql, oracle

Как правильно составить SQL запрос  для выполнения следующей задачи?

Есть база из которой нужно выгрузить данные так, чтобы получить разницу во времени относительно старого времени к более новому в рамках каждого ID для каждого значения времени (т.е. если есть 4 даты, то получить нужно разницу 1 - 2, 2 - 3, 3 - 4).

Пример данных:

```
id, "Время" 
 1, 20.63.2019 10:59:55 
 3, 20.03.2019 10:39:05
 3, 20.03.2019 08:24:20
 4, 20.03.2019 07:27:34 
 4, 20.03.2019 07:27:34
 3, 20.03.2019 10:25:53
 4, 20.03.2019 09:08:48 
 4, 20.03.2019 09:09:25 
 3, 20.03.2019 09:39:11 
 3, 20.03.2019 10:33:02
 3, 20.03.2019 10:32:59
 4, 20.03.2019 09:27:58
 2, 20.03.2019 11:45:17
 2, 20.03.2019 07:23:54 
 4, 20.03.2019 07:10:52 
 4, 20.03.2019 06:54:20 
 4, 20.03.2019 09:43:48
 3, 20.03.2019 10:32:56
 4, 20.03.2019 09:28:18 
 4, 20.03.2019 09:28:29
 2, 20.03.2019 09:34:06
 3, 20.03.2019 08:58:48
 3, 20.03.2019 10:21:08
 4, 20.03.2019 07:08:57 
 2, 20.03.2019 05:23:50 
 4, 20.03.2019 04:48:44 
 4, 20.03.2019 05:58:57
 2, 20.03.2019 04:20:56
 3, 20.03.2019 04:12:46 
 3, 20.03.2019 05:58:54
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
    id, 
    "Время", 
    Lag("Время") OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "Время" ASC) - "Время" diff 
  FROM yourtable
)
WHERE diff IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно так:

```
select 
    id, 
    ts "Время", 
    numtodsinterval (ts - lead (ts) over (partition by id order by ts desc), 'day') diff
from t
order by id, ts asc
;
```

Например, для `Id=2` выведет:

```
        ID Время               DIFF                                    
---------- ------------------- ----------------------------------------
         2 2019-03-20 04:20:56                                         
         2 2019-03-20 05:23:50 +00 01:02:54.000000                     
         2 2019-03-20 07:23:54 +00 02:00:04.000000                     
         2 2019-03-20 09:34:06 +00 02:10:12.000000                     
         2 2019-03-20 11:45:17 +00 02:11:11.000000
```

Полностью на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/789cdd/1).